# copy worksheet, code and button to a new file

Tags: excel, button, module, vba

I have created some codes and one of my requirement is to copy certain sheets, modules and buttons to refer those modules to a new workbook.

I am facing two problems:

1) While trying various things I am able to copy worksheets and module. However, the problem is when I copy module buttons to new worksheet, it still refers to the original file and not the new file which has been created.

2) When the button delete command runs it deletes buttons from existing workbook  and inserts a new button in existing workbook.

I can understand that somewhere I am not getting back to original file but not able to make out where and how to go to new file to execute the code.

The code for copying file, modules and buttons is as listed below.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim filename4 As String:
strFilename4 = "\Work Data " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmmss")
filename4 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & strFilename4 & ".xlsm"

Dim nm As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy
        For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
          If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print nm.Name & ": deleted"
            nm.Delete
          End If
        Next nm

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename4, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Const MODULE_NAME    As String = "DataValidityCheck"         ' Name of the module to transfer
Const TEMPFILE       As String = "c:\DataValidityCheck.bas" ' temp textfile
Dim WBK As Workbook
Set WBK = Workbooks.Open(filename4)

'Copy Module to New Workbook
   On Error Resume Next
   Set WBK = Workbooks(filename4)
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(MODULE_NAME).Export TEMPFILE
   WBK.VBProject.VBComponents.Import TEMPFILE
   Kill TEMPFILE

'Delete every shape in the Shapes collection
    Dim myshape As Shape
    For Each myshape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        myshape.Delete
    Next myshape

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2538, 4.5, 71.25, 14.25).Select

    With btn
        .Caption = "Validate Data" 'change the name of the button accordingly
        .OnAction = "msg"
    End With
    Selection.OnAction = "Workbook_Open"
 ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are not qualifying your workbooks correctly. Using `ThisWorkbook` will **always** signify the workbook running the code. Using `ActiveWorkbook` will **always** signify the workbook that is active at that moment in the codes execution. While there are perfectly legitimate times and places to use this, its generally a **bad** practice to do so, especially `ActiveWorkbook` (and `ActiveSheet` for that matter).

I have refactored your code with full comments to illustrate this, as well as cleaned up some other syntax related stuff that was in there.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Const MODULE_NAME    As String = "DataValidityCheck"         ' Name of the module to transfer
Const TEMPFILE       As String = "c:\DataValidityCheck.bas" ' temp textfile

'qualify main workbook
Dim wbkMain As Workbook
Set wbkMain = ThisWorkbook
'export desired module
With wbkMain

    .VBProject.VBComponents(MODULE_NAME).Export TEMPFILE

    'copy out sheets
    .Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy

End With

'qualify new workbook
Dim WBK As Workbook
Set WBK = ActiveWorkbook 'this is one of only a few times its required to use 'ActiveWorkbook'

'work directly with new workbook
With WBK

    'Copy Module to New Workbook
    .VBProject.VBComponents.Import TEMPFILE
    Kill TEMPFILE

    'delete bad names
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In .Names
        If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, "#REF!") Then nm.Delete
    Next

    'Delete every shape in the Shapes collection
    With .Sheets(1) 'change to 2 if you need sheet 2

        Dim myshape As Shape
        For Each myshape In .Shapes 'change to 2 if you need sheet 2
            myshape.Delete
        Next myshape

        .Buttons.Add(2538, 4.5, 71.25, 14.25).Select

        With Selection 'should really set this to a variable as well, but I didn't feel like looking the right syntax
            .Caption = "Validate Data" 'change the name of the button accordingly
            .OnAction = "msg" 'Workbook_Open if need be
        End With

    End With

    'finally save the new workbook
    Dim filename4 As String, strFilename4 As String
    strFilename4 = "\Work Data " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy hhmmss")
    filename4 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & strFilename4 & ".xlsm"

    .SaveAs Filename:=filename4, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
        , CreateBackup:=False

    .Close True 'don't need since you just saved, but why not

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Change this line: `With WKB` to `With WBK` otherwise the code will not produce the expected results.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @EEM. I fixed it.